# Recursion theoretical Characterization of time complexity classes

Tags: lo.logic, computational-complexity, computability-theory

Is there any known Recursion theoretical Characterization of time complexity classes like $\mathsf{DTIME(n^k)}$ or $\mathsf{NTIME(n^k)}$ for some fixed $k$?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you consider a "recursion-theoretic classification"?

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Some characterization like Cobham recursive functions or Primitive recursive functions.

Comment: Ah, so you're looking for a definition of the form "start with these basic functions, and close under these operations"?

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Yes. a characterization like the one you described.

Comment: I would incorporate that explicitly into the question - I would consider "computable by a deterministic Turing machine in polynomial time" to *already* be a recursion-theoretic characterization.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: As far as I know recursion theoretic characterizations are machine independent. Am I wrong?

Comment: Hm, I wasn't aware that the phrase had a narrow meaning - I interpreted it simply as "characterization using the ideas/concepts of recursion theory," but googling around it does appear to be consistently used to describe machine-independent characterizations as you say. (Learn something new every day!) Incidentally, there is *another* kind of machine-independent characterization, quite independent of the "built-up-from-functions-and-rules" style: *logical complexity* - the primitive recursive functions are those provably total in $RCA_0$, and polytime corresponds to bounded arithmetic. (contd)

Comment: Would you consider such a characterization to be recursion-theoretic?

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Yes, actually my motivation for asking this question is axiomatizing an equational theory for $\mathsf{DTIME(n^k)}$ reasoning like $\mathsf{PV}$ which is provided polytime reasoning. but I can not find a way to formalize them in a natural way.